# SQL error primary key incorrect values

Tags: sql, primary-key, mariadb

I want to import data with an SQL query. Here is my very stripped down version of the code, which still gives me the error `#1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (`uid` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (30046454912);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (30057490115);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (30061940182);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (30078940114);
```

There are other columns, which I have excluded from this example since it seems to go wrong with the primary key.

Server type is MariaDB, executing SQL from phpMyAdmin.

I'm sure I am overlooking something ... Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? Please let me know with a comment how my question can be improved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

30046454912 is greater than the maximum integer value of 2147483647, so the insert changes the value to the maximum integer value.  In order to get this to work, change your uid column to a long type.

Comment: Ah, I thought it had to be something like that, thank you very much! I'll test this out and accept your answer when it let's me :)

Comment: By "long type", he means `BIGINT`.